# Why is the largest signed 32 bit integer prime?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

This may be subjective, but does anyone have any insight into why this is the case? This struck me while considering that it's also the eigth Mersenne prime (2^31-1=2147483647).

> I'm now wondering why this might be the case.

**UPDATE:**
It's been pointed out that the relationship doesn't necessarily hold for larger storage classes, e.g., 2^63 - 1 is not prime.

Comment: Not for 64 bit, 63 is composite.

Comment: I'm going to say that I doubt there's a reason...like Fermat's conjecture that $2^{2^n}+1$ is always prime, there can be a few random examples, but it doesn't always mean that there is a pattern.

Comment: The Largest 64 bit prime is 18446744073709551557, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621251.aspx. See also http://primes.utm.edu/lists/2small/0bit.html

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I think that's fair. I now even feel a little silly about the question, as vaguely worded as it is. Thanks for the patience...

Comment: 127 is prime, but 255, 511, 1023, 2047, 4095 are composite. 8191 is prime again. 16383, 32767, 65535 are composite. 131071 is prime.

Comment: That would suggest the largest unsigned value for a 'sufficiently large storage class' may be a decent prime candidate -- more or less Fermat's conjecture mentioned above for sufficiently large n.

Comment: It really would help if you switched to symbols. I think by largest unsigned value you mean $$ 2^{2^n} - 1  $$ which is always divisible by 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why is $3$ prime?  I don't really know that there are meaningful answers to these kinds of questions.  The best I can think of is some reasons it is not obviously composite, e.g. since $5$ is prime $2^5 - 1 = 31$ is not obviously composite (and it turns out to be prime) hence $2^{31} - 1$ is not obviously composite.  This is two applications of the "lemma" that if $p$ is prime then $2^p - 1$ is not obviously composite.

Note that any prime factor of $2^p - 1$ has to be congruent to $1 \bmod p$ by Fermat's little theorem, so it is "easier" for such numbers to be prime.